# php date always displayed in Dutch

Tags: magento-1.9, php, localisation, date, translate

I currently use the following code to display some date inside my Magento store:

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'nl_NL'); 
$today = new Zend_Date($_product->getData('delivery_eta'), 'MM-dd-yyyy'); 
$date = Mage::helper('core')->formatDate($today, Mage_Core_Model_Locale::FORMAT_TYPE_FULL, false); 
echo $date;
```

But when a for example Google Chrome visitor with a specific language goes to the website, this is translated to their language. I want to disable this and display the date always in Dutch.

How can I fix this?

I already tried to add the line `setlocale(LC_TIME, 'nl_NL');` and `setlocale(LC_ALL, 'nl_NL');` but that does not work. It is still translated. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this ...

```
$locale = 'nl_NL';
$date = new Zend_Date($_product->getData('delivery_eta'));
$date->setLocale($locale);
echo $date->toString(Zend_Date::DATE_LONG);
```

Comment: Thanks! That is almost perfect. I only miss the day of the week. How can I also add the day of the week? That is wat I currently have.

Comment: @HenkZ try `Zend_Date::DATE_FULL` instead. Other formats here: https://framework.zend.com/manual/1.10/en/zend.date.constants.html